# ant install error: BUILD FAILED java returned exit code 1

Tags: java, jdk, database

I'm trying to install [DSpace 6.3](https://duraspace.org/dspace/download/) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When I'm installing `ant` I get:

```
BUILD FAILED error...
```

When I enter `ant-fresh install` on the terminal, it gives me this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/build/dspace-6.3-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/build.xml:789: Java returned: 1
Total time: 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to edit the file

```
nano /dspace/config/local.cfg.EXAMPLE
```

change the `db.password` = with the password you entered twice after the command:

```
createuser -U postgres -d -A -P dspace
```

save the changes to file `local.cfg.EXAMPLE` and save it as `local.cfg`, then run the command

```
sudo ant fresh_install
```

again and this will do it.